# Crust and crumb

Tags: phrases, idioms

" Crust and crumb " is the title of an 1895 picture " toy " book in the Montgomery Ward catalog. The title feels like an idiom. I welcome input.

Comment: I assume you're asking what it means? Can you provide the source so that we can see the full context?

Comment: 'Both the outside and inside of the loaf'. There seem to be a lot of bakeries and sandwich shops using the name.

Comment: *Crust and Crumb: Master Formulas for Serious Bread Bakers* by Peter Reinhart is sold everywhere.

Comment: 'Crust and Crumb' is more a catchy business name like 'Slug and Lettuce' or 'The Knickknack Shack', though it does seem to have originated as a catchy book title. Like 'Eats, Shoots and Leaves'. So not a mainstream fixed expression.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Crust and crumb are the two major components of cooked bread, both formed from the same dough by different processes. The crust is the hard outer surface of a loaf formed due to the evaporation of most of the water in the dough and commonly with browning from the Maillard reaction and caramelization. The crumb is the soft interior where there is much less evaporation. Together they make up bread.

Sources:

- Y.M. Mohd Jusoh, N.L. Chin, Y.A. Yusof, R. Abdul Rahman, "[Bread crust thickness measurement using digital imaging and L a b colour system](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0260877409001885)", *Journal of Food Engineering*, Volume 94, Issues 3–4, October 2009, Pages 366-371, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfoodeng.2009.04.002
- F.M. Vanin, T. Lucas, G. Trystram, "[Crust formation and its role during bread baking](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0924224409001307)", *Trends in Food Science & Technology*, Volume 20, Issue 8, August 2009, Pages 333-343, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tifs.2009.04.001

Comment: baked bread, right? Rather than cooked...but I take your point.